# Using Double in Switch Statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, switch-statement

All of the values below are doubles, yet switch requires a integer value. Is there anyway around this?

```
switch(fivePercentValue){
case floor((5*fivePercentValue) / 100):
    fivePercent_.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    fivePercentLabel_.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    break;
case ceil((5*fivePercentValue) / 100):
    fivePercent_.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    fivePercentLabel_.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    break;
default:
    fivePercent_.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    fivePercentLabel_.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    break;
```

Comment: comparison of floating points for equality is never really a good idea so `switch` over a float is a really bad idea.

Comment: The `case` values must be compile-time constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probable better of just using if else and testing for ranges but you can perform some maths on your `fivePercentValue` and then convert it to an integer so that different integers represent different ranges for example

```
switch( (int)(value*10.0) )
{
    case 0:        // this is 0.0 <= value < 0.1
        break;
    case 1:        // this is 0.1 <= value < 0.2
        break;
    case 2:        // this is 0.2 <= value < 0.3
        break;
    ....
}
```